# How to check if an integer is in a set of given ranges?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, hashmap

Let's say there is a large set of ranges. For example a set with size 5000:

```
[100,200],[1,59],[3,5],[70,70]...
```

How to check if an integer n falls in at least one of these ranges efficiently in Java?

Comment: Why do you have a python tag on this question?

Comment: What Object are these ranges represented by? Integer arrays of length 2 or a Range Class?

Comment: Merge any overlapping ranges, then sort them. Use binary search to check if the test value is contained. Or, if the domain is reasonably small, build a BitSet where all of the bits 100-200, 1-59, etc are set, and just use `bitset.get(testValue)`.

Comment: How you approach the problem depends on the upper and lower bounds of the ranges and how many items you have to test for membership.  If the highest and lowest possible range bounds differ by a "small" amount (i.e. less than 10,000) then an array-based solution might be best. If the bounds are a lot larger then a @AndyTurner's suggestion would apply.  You haven't given us enough information, or showed what you've tried.

Answer (score 5):

The time efficient way to do this is to create a `Bitset` with a bit set for all of the integers in all of the sets.  Then you can test for membership with a single `O(1)` call.

The problem is that if the combined range of the integers is large, then the `Bitset` will take a lot of memory.

A second approach is to combine overlapping ranges, and construct a `TreeMap<Integer, Integer>` where the key is the lower bound and value is the upper bound of each combined range.  Then use `TreeMap::floorKey` and a test to find the matching ranges.  This procedure is `O(logN)` where `N` is the number of combined ranges.  Space usage will be `O(N)`.

Comment: An alternative to the second approach is to use something like [Guava's `RangeSet`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/RangeSet.html), which simply takes a little of the drudgery out of the combining of the ranges and querying for the contained value.